# Encoding options not supported in 1.8: r:UTF-8

Tags: ruby, uglifyjs

I am trying to use Ruby Uglifier gem, but it's giving this warning and the output javascript is not minified:

> /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/uglifier-1.2.7/lib/uglifier.rb:51: warning: encoding options not supported in 1.8: r:UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

The easiest answer for this is you need to upgrade to ruby 1.9.  1.8 does not support specifying a character encoding.

Tl;dr

The person who made this gem did not properly specify the supported Ruby versions in their `gemspec` when they built the gem, so it allowed you to install it, but it will be non-functioning due to the hard coded `UTF-8` encoding.  You could possibly edit the gem to remove this, but there is no guarantee that it would work, as they may be using UTF-8 specific characters in the gem somewhere.  I highly recommend upgrading to 1.9.

Comment: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/uglifier-1.2.7/lib/uglifier.rb line 51 and  remove UTF-8 in the File open statement's params. 

Or continue using it as it is... It is a Warning